# NX_NOT_CONNECTED status returned from nx_tcp_client_socket_connect API while trying to run TCP echo client example using STM32H757 and NetXduo

Tags: embedded, threadx

I am working on a project to establish TCP communication with STM32H757 Eval Kit and PC. But the TCP communication is unsuccessful. (ThreadX, NetXduo are used)

Steps:

1. nx_tcp_socket_create -> Successful
2. nx_tcp_client_socket_bind -> Successful
3. nx_tcp_client_socket_connect -> Unsuccessful (NX_NOT_CONNECTED status returned)

I created STM32H757 project with NetXduo enabled, referred below example repo and ported neccessary files.

https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-h7/tree/f25d657a4de4aac6dba48df28b96238479d73ca0/Projects/NUCLEO-H723ZG/Applications/NetXDuo/Nx_TCP_Echo_Client